# Android Spinner How to Show Current Value From SQL

Tags: android, sql, arrays, spinner

I have an android app using sql lite with two tables.  Table_1 can be referenced by Table_2 multiple times.  Table_2 references table1 by the primary key from table_1. I have a form to edit the data in the second table.  I have a spinner in this form that loads the name column from table_1.  Everything works good on the database side, however I am unable to load a "default" value for the spinner box.  The spinner box will always show the first name in table_1.  I would like to use setSelection() method to set the position to the currently selected name.  Since the data in table_1 can be modified, deleted or updated the primary key does not match the row position in the database, I can not simply set the setSelection to the primary key.

I have tried the getPosition() method but I get an error that a cursor can not return an integer value.

Answer (score 0):

Now working.  Ended up creating an arraylist for the primary key.

```
position = arraylist.indexOf(String.valueOf(primarykeyID));
```

The key to working was converting the integer value to a string value